# How to requests-request_id-receipt-get?

Tags: node.js, uber-api

I'm trying to get the receipt but I can't!
I already set "request_receipt" in AUTHORIZATIONS on my app and nothing change.
What I have to do to get de receipt?

```
<script>
var headers = {
    'Accept-Language':'en_US',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
};

  function callback(error, response, body) {
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      }else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
          headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${jsonBody.access_token}`;
          getUserHistory(req,res);
      }
  }
  request.post(options, callback);
});

function getUserHistory(req,res){
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/history',
        headers:headers
    };

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {

    if(error){
        console.log(error);
      }else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var bodyJson = JSON.parse(body);
          bodyJson.history.map(function(model){
                  var options = {
                      url: 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/'+model.request_id+'/receipt',
                      headers:headers
                  };
                  request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
                      if(error){
                          console.log(error);
                        }else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                            res.send(body);
                        }
                  });

              })
          }
    });

}
</script>
```

Running this code, I can see this message:

[image]

Comment: This message is returned when users are not authorized to access specific scope. In your case, it is "request_receipt". So something is not right in your authentication process - and your access_token does not have access to : "requests/'+model.request_id+'/receipt" endpoint.

Comment: Right. The first time I logged in, one screen asking permissions appeared, but now it doesn't appear anymore! And I'm using anonymous window chrome!
What do you suggest @SasaJovanovic?

Comment: Login to https://riders.uber.com with your Uber account. Under "Profile" you will see section "Connected Accounts". Disconnect your user from the application you connected. And try to authorize this user again with proper scopes added to the authorize endpoint: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=YOUR_LIST_OF_SCOPES.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.
But when I disconnected this message appears:
"SOMETHING WENT WRONG

There has been an error, and we are currently looking into it. For further assistance, visit our support website."
Is this normal? kkkkkk

Comment: Other thing, now the permission screen appears, but, the request_receipt no! Is that currect?

Comment: On the permission screen, you suppose to see all scopes where you authorize access to, so something is wrong with the scope list you using in your authorize endpoint that I mentioned in the previous comment.